# why there is this difference in initializing global variable between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, global-variables, variable-declaration

Have a look at these programs:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i;       //C implementation works fine with this initialization of variable i
i=108;

int main()
{
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

While in this code (c++ version) it throws error:

> ‘i’ does not name a type
>    i=99;

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int i;
i=99;

int main()
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I read that what causes to run successfully the **C** version is *implicit int* which was later removed from C99 version.

1: Is this hindering the **C++** version to run successfully?

2: If this *implicit int* is reason behind 1st code then why compiler doesn't throw an error of 'i' being defined twice?

Please point my wrong understanding of the concept.

Comment: One line declaration and initialization will work. [Check here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm)

Comment: Hint: Even <C99 this `float i; i=42;` wouldn't compile.

Comment: And it is invalid code in Python or Brainfuck. Why do you expect different languages to have identical syntax and/or behaviour?

Comment: `int i;` is a [tentative definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern#Tentative_definitions) in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, this in global scope

```
int i;
i = 42;
```

takes the 2nd line as a re-definition of what had been defined in the 1st. If the types match the compiler accepts it and merges the "two `i`s" into one.

In the above example the types do match, due to implicitly applying the "*make anything unknown an `int`*" rule to the 2nd definition of `i`.

The following lines for example won't compile:

```
float f;
f = 42;
```

as the 2nd `f` would be taken as an `int`, which does not match the type of the 1st `f`, which is a `float`.

---

Not 100% sure about C++, but I assume this "*make anything unknown an `int`*" rule simply does not exist in C++. So in global scope something like `i = 42;` would not be valid, which is completely independent to whether an `i` had been declared or defined before or not.

Comment: to expand that:  Even in C++, `extern int i; int i = 42;` will be  accepted

Comment: This answers one of my questions, can you please help me in the second one?

Answer (score 3):

At that point in the file, any line of code must be a declaration; it can't be an assignment to an existing object.

In C, there is a rule that a declaration can leave off the type (which will default to `int`), so your line *can* be parsed as a declaration (and definition with initialiser) in that language. Furthermore, since C has [*tentative definitions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern#Tentative_definitions), this "second" definition  is allowed:

```
int i;        // tentative definition
int i = 42;   // "int" added automatically
```

These two rules combine to make the code valid in C. C++ has neither of them. So, in C++, `i = 42` is not a declaration and your code is invalid. Period.

Comment: So when int i; is written at global scope, is it merely a declaration? Not definition?

Comment: @infinite Actually, the term is "tentative *definition*".  If there is no other definition, it's a definition (with zero initialization).  If there *is* another definition (as in this case), it's a declaration.  C had to keep this confusion for historical reasons - C++ decided to throw it out.

Comment: @MartinBonner: "*with zero initialization*" well, the implicit initialisation which applies to all globals and statics takes place. In this case the `int` `i` would be initialised to `0`.

Comment: @alk:  *zero initialization* may be a C++ term.  The meaning is as you describe (integral and floating point variables become zero, pointers become null pointers - only unsigned integral values are guaranteed to be all value bits zero though.)

Comment: It dawned me quite soon after having placed my comment, that I might have misunderstood you. Thanks for confirming anyways ... :-)